# Phase Difference In SHM Of Two Simple Pendulums

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, conventions, oscillators

[image]

Figure shows two simple pendulum with their initial projections velocities $v_1$ and $v_2$ and angular positions $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Let $A_1$ be amplitude of oscillation of (A). Let $A_2$ be amplitude of oscillation of (B).

Using equations of SHM we get:

For $A$: $v_1=\sqrt\frac{g}{l}\sqrt{A_1^2-(l\alpha)^2} \implies A_1=\sqrt{l^2\alpha^2+\left(\frac{v_1^2l}{g}\right)}$

For $B$: $v_2=\sqrt\frac{g}{l}\sqrt{A_2^2-(l\beta)^2} \implies A_1=\sqrt{l^2\beta^2+\left(\frac{v_2^2l}{g}\right)}$

Let us use projection of SHM on a circle's diameter to find phase. Let $\omega$ be in anticlockwise direction. Now, since A is moving back towards mean position the phase of it should be $\phi_1=2\pi-\sin^{-1}(\frac{l\alpha}{A_1})$ and phase of (B) will be $\phi_2=\sin^{-1}(\frac{l\beta}{A_2})$ as it is moving away from mean position.

So $\Delta \phi= 2\pi-\sin^{-1}(\frac{l\alpha}{A_1})-\sin^{-1}(\frac{l\beta}{A_2})$.

However, my teacher said that my method is wrong and the phase difference should actually be just $\sin^{-1}(\frac{l\alpha}{A_1})+\sin^{-1}(\frac{l\beta}{A_2})$.

Why is it so? Can someone explain ?

Comment: Why are you using an opposite frame for A and B? There is no reason to write  "since A is moving back towards mean position" and do differently for B, shouldn't you use the same convention for *both* pendulums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are both right.
It all depends which of the two oscillations is the reference one.
Is it red lagging or leading green?

[image]

In the graph above you could say that red is **lagging** green by a time $t_1+t_2$ or that red is **leading** green by $T-(t_1+t_2)$ where $T$ is the period of an oscillation.
In terms of angle, a period $T$ is equivalent to an angle $2\pi$ radians.

Comment: In that case I think it is even correct to say that the red is "leading " green by $-t_1-t_2$. So phase difference of $\phi$ is equivalent to $\pm(nT\pm\phi)$ (where $n$ is any integer) and we can choose it as we wish. But is there any convention to be followed while choosing phase difference ?

Comment: Often the phase angle spans $180^\circ$ from $-90^\circ$ to $+90^\circ$ or $0^\circ$ to $180^\circ$.